# Angular.js - updating parent scope from directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to update a dict of values in a parent scope from a directive. 
The dict parent is updated through a function (explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs)) so i dont really understand why when i print `values` i see them but when binding with a `pre` tag it's not changing. 
Plus, why is `field.error` not showing in the directive template ?

I set up a simplified exmaple of my problem in this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/efoRaNUc/2/edit?html,js,console,output)

Angular newbi, and quite a frustrated one... Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are [missing a `scope.$apply`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#methods) when you handle the JS events in your directive.

The event handling happens in pure JS, *outside* the angular context and when you invoke the function on the parent scope, you are invoking it as you would invoke a function on any other plain JS object. Keeping plain JS objects instead of creating their own object hierarchies where they could intercept function calls is a design choice which Angular made different from, say, `ember`.

The value *does* change on the scope, it is just that Angular is not aware of it. The next time a `$digest` loop is triggered by *anything* (say a different button click with an `ng-click`), the change would show up. What we can do, however, is to make sure that the `$digest` loop is triggered by explicitly calling `scope.$apply()`.

The fix is this:

```js
element.bind("blur change keyup", function() { 
  // This will tell Angular to rerun the $digest loop
  // as we are changing some variables which Angular
  // should be informed about.
  scope.$apply(function () {  
    var val = element.find("input").val();
    var oldval = scope.values[scope.field.name];
    if (oldval !== val && isValid(val))
      scope.set_value(scope.field.name,val);
    //else
    //  scope.set_value(scope.field.name,undefined);
  });
});
```

Working demo: http://jsbin.com/inoKOVU/1/edit

Comment: Why is that ? i'm using a function to update the parent scope so ... from what i red it's using references to the parent so, where exactly is this code "running" without using apply ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer @musically_ut. Can I set up two way binding with the parent dict using this method ? or i have to define an attribute and bind it to the directives scope with `"="` ?

Comment: You can use an attribute on the directive and `$watch` the value inherited from the parent scope.